# Are this type of cyclotomic polynomials irreducible over a finite field?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am trying to fully understand this particular case of cyclotomic polynomials. Given the cyclotomic polynomials $\phi(x) = x^n+1$, where $n$ is a power of $2$, I want to understand how this polynomial works being the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]$, where $q$ is a prime number. Equivalently, how $R_q = \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/\langle x^n+1 \rangle$ works when $n$ is a power of $2$.

In particular:

- Is $R_q$ a field? Equivalently, when $x^{2^{\kappa}}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ with $\kappa \geq 1$ (should it be $\kappa \geq 2$?). I assume it never happens since we refer to $R_q$ as a ring.
- Are this cyclotomic polynomials irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$? Anyways, as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^n+1 \rangle$ can not be a field even if $x^{2^{\kappa}}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^{2^k}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ for all non-negative integers $k$. This can be shown by applying Eisenstein on $f(x+1)$ No idea whether this helps for the questions.

Comment: @MarkBennet Could you edit your comment?

Comment: Note that $x^{4n}+1=\left(x^{2n}+\sqrt 2 x^n+1\right)\left(x^{2n}-\sqrt 2 x^n+1\right)$, so if $2$ is a square, $x^{4n}+1$ is reducible. For example, if $q=7$ we have $3^2\equiv 2$ and $x^4+1=(x^2+3x+1)(x^2-3x+1)$. Quadratic reciprocity enables us to identify the primes for which $2$ is a square.

Comment: @BeanGuy Now done. When I wrote it I couldn't see what was wrong - I had to delete it to correct it (wrong bracket in exponent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Small note: it's a standard convention that $q$ denotes a prime power so I'll write $p$ for the prime.)

All of the cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

The factorization of cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (and even over $\mathbb{F}_q$) can be completely understood by considering the action of the [Frobenius map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism) $x \mapsto x^p$ on their roots. In general, the irreducible factors of a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ correspond precisely to orbits of the Frobenius map acting on its roots over a splitting field (exercise). For cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_n(x)$ we can be really explicit about the action of the Frobenius map because it sends a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^p$. The degree of the irreducible factor containing $\zeta_n$ (equivalently, degree of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$) is then the smallest $k$ such that $\zeta_n^{p^k} = \zeta_n$, hence the smallest $k$ such that

$$p^k \equiv 1 \bmod n.$$

This is exactly the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) $\text{ord}_n(p)$ of $p \bmod n$.

> **Corollary:** $\Phi_n(x)$ is irreducible $\bmod p$ if and only if $p$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $\bmod n$.

(This whole discussion requires that $\gcd(n, p) = 1$. If $p \mid n$ then $\Phi_n(x) \bmod p$ has repeated roots.)

If we now specialize to $n = 2^m$ a power of two, so that $\Phi_{2^m}(x) = x^{2^{m-1}} + 1$, we get the following:

- when $m = 1$ we have $\Phi_2(x) = x + 1$, which is always irreducible.
- when $m = 2$ we have $\Phi_4(x) = x^2 + 1$, which is irreducible $\bmod p$ iff $p$ is a primitive root $\bmod 4$, which occurs iff $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.
- when $m \ge 3$ there are no primitive roots $\bmod 2^m$ so $\Phi_{2^m}(x)$ is never irreducible $\bmod p$ for any prime $p$.

The case $p = 2$ has to be handled separately but in that case $\Phi_{2^m}(x) = (x + 1)^{2^{m-1}}$. It follows that $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/\Phi_{2^m}(x)$ is a field iff either $m = 1$, or $m = 2$ and $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

It's a little surprising that irreducible polynomials which are reducible $\bmod p$ for every prime $p$ exist, and $\Phi_8(x) = x^4 + 1$ is in some sense a minimal example of such a polynomial (in particular it has minimal degree; this is impossible for a quadratic or a cubic polynomial). You can check using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E4+%2B+1+mod+3), for example, that

$$x^4 + 1 \equiv (x^2 + x - 1)(x^2 - x - 1) \bmod 3$$
$$x^4 + 1 \equiv (x^2 + 2)(x^2 - 2) \bmod 5$$
$$x^4 + 1 \equiv (x^2 + 3x + 1)(x^2 - 3x + 1) \bmod 7$$
$$x^4 + 1 \equiv (x^2 + 3x - 1)(x^2 - 3x - 1) \bmod 11$$
$$x^4 + 1 \equiv (x^2 + 5)(x^2 - 5) \bmod 13$$
$$x^4 + 1 \equiv (x + 2)(x - 2)(x + 8)(x - 8) \bmod 17$$

and so forth. In general there are four different patterns of factorization $\bmod p$ depending on the value of $p \bmod 8$:

If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, then $\zeta_8^p = \zeta_8$ so $x^4 + 1$ splits into linear factors

$$(x - \zeta_8)(x - \zeta_8^3)(x - \zeta_8^{-3})(x - \zeta_8^{-1}).$$

This also happens for $p = 2$ but the argument is easier: $x^4 + 1 \equiv (x + 1)^4 \bmod 2$.

If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 8$ then $\zeta_8^p = \zeta_8^3 \neq \zeta_8$ but $\zeta_8^{p^2} = \zeta_8^9 = \zeta_8$ so $x^4 + 1$ splits into quadratic factors

$$(x - \zeta_8)(x - \zeta_8^3), (x - \zeta_8^{-3})(x - \zeta_8^{-1})$$

with constant terms $\zeta_8^4 = \zeta_8^{-4} = -1$. The linear terms turn out to be the two square roots of $-2$ (and you can check this by squaring them); this reflects the identity

$$x^4 + 1 = (x^2 - 1)^2 + 2x^2 = (x^2 + \sqrt{-2} x - 1)(x^2 - \sqrt{-2} x - 1)$$

over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$ which is one of the three quadratic subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$.

If $p \equiv -3 \bmod 8$ then $\zeta_8^p = \zeta_8^{-3} \neq \zeta_8$ but $\zeta_8^{p^2} = \zeta_8^9 = \zeta_8$ so $x^4 + 1$ splits into quadratic factors

$$(x - \zeta_8)(x - \zeta_8^{-3}), (x - \zeta_8^3)(x - \zeta_8^{-1})$$

with constant terms $\zeta_8^{-2} = \zeta_4^{-1}$ and $\zeta_8^2 = \zeta_4$ the two primitive $4^{th}$ roots of unity. The linear terms both vanish since $\zeta_8^4 = -1$; this reflects the identity

$$x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + i)(x^2 - i)$$

over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, another one of the three quadratic subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$.

Finally, if $p \equiv -1 \bmod 8$ then $\zeta_8^p = \zeta_8^{-1} \neq \zeta_8$ but $\zeta_8^{p^2} = \zeta_8$ so $x^4 + 1$ splits into quadratic factors

$$(x - \zeta_8)(x - \zeta_8^{-1}), (x  - \zeta_8^3)(x - \zeta_8^{-3})$$

with constant terms $1$. The linear terms turn out to be the two square roots of $2$ (you can again check this by squaring them); this reflects the identity

$$x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + 1)^2 - 2x^2 = (x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1)(x^2 - \sqrt{2} x + 1)$$

over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, the final quadratic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$.

Altogether the phenomena happening here for $x^4 + 1$ reflect three special cases of [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) (and these special cases can actually be proven this way), and one way to think about what's going on instead of using the Frobenius map is to argue that $\left( \frac{-1}{p} \right) \left( \frac{2}{p} \right) = \left( \frac{-2}{p} \right)$ which means at least one of $-1, 2, -2$ must always be a quadratic residue $\bmod p$, each of which leads to one of the three quadratic patterns of factorization above.

Comment: Just thanks for answer.